# Can Munchkin Quest be used for classic Munchkin?

Tags: munchkin-quest, munchkin

I received "Munchkin Quest" as a gift. I had expected to get the classic "Munchkin"; I don't really know this variant but exchanging it is not an option.

I wish to play this with some of my not-so-board-game-aholic friends, and I imagine that the classic version is way easier, what with the tiles and creatures and markers taken out of the equation. I hope to "upgrade" them as time goes by, but better to start them on Level 1, right?

So, finally, my question: Can one play a round of classic Munchkin using a box of Munchkin Quest? Or, are there prohibitive differences?

Thanks...

Comment: Munchkin Quest is a far superior game to Munchkin anyways. And it really isn't difficult to teach people to play either game.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

Longer explanation:

They are **totally different games**. [Munchkin](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1927/munchkin) is a card game. [Munchkin Quest](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/29678/munchkin-quest) is a board game. They share:

- A theme: *Kill the monsters, take their stuff, stab your buddy* - parodying power-gaming RPGers of a certain stripe
- An artist: [John Kovalic](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/6815/john-kovalic)
- A goal: Reach level 10 first
- A Publisher: [Steve Jackson Games](http://sjgames.com/)
- An official website: http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/

But the materials in MQ will not allow you to play Munchkin. And no amount of Munchkin sets will allow you to play MQ.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no on the sheer fact that so many of the MQ cards play off of the tiles.  You'd have to sift through and take out all of those, and that's just not fun.

Answer (score -2):

While the games seem similar, in that they share the same **concept**, **goal**, and ***certain* mechanics**, they are two **DIFFERENT** games, that function in ***COMPLETELY DIFFERENT*** ways.

tl,dr; No, you can't.

Comment: -1, because this answer doesn't contain any new info. Can you add any additional information to your answer that isn't covered already by Gomads answer? If so, I'll gladly give you the upvote.

Comment: Leave it, I have not played MQ, so I don't have precise examples. :/

Comment: @Zagstrug So why answer a question for a game that you have never played, which already has a valid and accepted answer with numerous upvotes, where you don't provide any real information at all?